# MS Word Scraping works for docx but not doc files

Tags: python, python-docx

I have the following code that is looking at multiple word files nad pulling all of the text into a single row per file. This works fine for docx files, but is failing for doc's

Error:

```
    raise PackageNotFoundError(
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'C:\Users\xxx\sample.doc'
```

```
for w in wrd:
    doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(resumes, w))
    result = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
    result = ':::'.join(result)
    files.append(w)
    text.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`python-docx` only works for Word 2007+ `.docx` files. These files are a zip archive of XML files (called "parts"). The legacy `.doc` format is a binary format and completely different. There is no Python package for reading the legacy `.doc` format as far as I know.